# Google-Maps-iOS-SDK Crash when selecting marker

Tags: ios, google-maps, crash, google-maps-markers

I'm having a random crash, while selecting a marker on the map. The markers as you can see in the code are customs and when they are tapped marker's icon is hidden and a custom information view is placed. 
All the delegate methods are executed normally every time, so the crash is not directly in my code but I might be doing something to "upset" google maps

```
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019a8f9cc8 __kill + 8
1   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x000000019a977b18 _sigtramp + 68
2   QuartzCore                      0x0000000190908038 -[CALayer _renderBorderInContext:] + 112
3   QuartzCore                      0x0000000190906b64 -[CALayer renderInContext:] + 1032
4   SP                              0x000000010036abf4 -[GMSMapView setSelectedMarker:] + 196
5   SP                              0x000000010036befc -[GMSMapView didTapMarker:] + 112
6   SP                              0x0000000100381830 -[GMSMarker wasTapped] + 60
7   SP                              0x000000010028fa14 -[GMSVectorMapView didTapAt:] + 1252
8   UIKit                           0x0000000190e6ec48 _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 212
9   UIKit                           0x0000000190cfd284 -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:] + 376
10  UIKit                           0x00000001910fc03c ___UIGestureRecognizerUpdate_block_invoke + 56
11  UIKit                           0x0000000190cbe240 _UIGestureRecognizerRemoveObjectsFromArrayAndApplyBlocks + 284
12  UIKit                           0x0000000190cbcb1c _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 208
13  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018dcc3854 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 28
14  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018dcc0adc __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368
15  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018dcc0e68 __CFRunLoopRun + 760
16  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018dc01dcc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 448
17  GraphicsServices                0x00000001938e9c08 GSEventRunModal + 164
18  UIKit                           0x0000000190d32fc0 UIApplicationMain + 1152
19  SP                              0x00000001000590e0 main (main.m:14)
20  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000019a7ffa9c start + 0
```

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Now here is the code for the map.
I'm using storyboard with autolayout

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

#ifdef DEBUG
    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:40.780528
                                                            longitude:-73.961009
                                                                 zoom:kZoomMin];
#else
    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:[LocationManager sharedInstance].currentLocation.coordinate.latitude
                                                            longitude:[LocationManager sharedInstance].currentLocation.coordinate.longitude
                                                                 zoom:12];
#endif

    CGFloat width = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
    CGFloat height = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;

    //Setting map
    self.mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height) camera:camera];
    self.mapView.settings.compassButton = NO;
    self.mapView.settings.myLocationButton = NO;
    self.mapView.accessibilityElementsHidden = NO;

    self.mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    self.mapView.buildingsEnabled = NO;
    self.mapView.indoorEnabled = NO;
    self.mapView.delegate = self;

…
}
```

The description of markerInfoWindow delegate method says I should avoid changing map size beyond 500x500 px and avoid changing the markers, I had removed all the marker's calls but it crashes anyway
I've try to check if I was using mapView on main thread, I checked it with [NSThread currentThread] and it seems to be always in main thread, please let me know if there is a better way to check it

```
#pragma mark - GMSMapViewDelegate

- (UIView *)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView
   markerInfoWindow:(GMSMarker *)marker
{

    UIView *infoWindow = [[UIView alloc] init];
    infoWindow.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 240, 54);
    infoWindow.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    infoWindow.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    infoWindow.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    infoWindow.layer.borderColor = (__bridge CGColorRef)([UIColor blackColor]);
    infoWindow.layer.borderWidth = 5;

    ParkingLot *parkingLot = (ParkingLot *)marker.userData;

    if (![parkingLot isKindOfClass:[ParkingLot class]])
    {
        return nil;
    }

    NSString *backgroundImageName = nil;

    switch ([parkingLot.parentCompanyId intValue])
    {
        case 1:
            backgroundImageName = @"00_logo_pin_globo_b.png";
            break;

        case 2:
            backgroundImageName = @"00_logo_pin_globo_c.png";
            break;

        case 3:
            backgroundImageName = @"00_logo_pin_globo_a.png";
            break;

    }

    UIImageView *background = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:backgroundImageName]];
    CGRect frame = background.frame;
    frame.origin.y++;
    frame.origin.x++;
    [background setFrame:frame];
    [infoWindow addSubview:background];

    UILabel *locationName = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    locationName.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12];
    locationName.frame = CGRectMake(45, 10, 110, 13);
    locationName.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [infoWindow addSubview:locationName];

    if ([marker.userData isKindOfClass:[SearchResult class]])
    {
        Address *address = (Address *)marker.userData;
        ASSERT_CLASS(address, Address);

        UILabel *addressLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        addressLabel.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, 60, 20);
        addressLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12];
        [addressLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [infoWindow addSubview:addressLabel];

        addressLabel.text = address.name;

        [infoWindow setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 30)];
        infoWindow.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        [background removeFromSuperview];
    }
    else
    {
        UILabel *addressLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        addressLabel.frame = CGRectMake(45, 22, 90, 20);
        addressLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:8];
        addressLabel.text = parkingLot.lotAddress;
        addressLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        [addressLabel setNumberOfLines:2];

        [infoWindow addSubview:addressLabel];

        if ([parkingLot.hasCoupon intValue] == 1)
        {
            UIImageView *hasCouponImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"00_logo_icon_%_.png"]];
            [hasCouponImageView setCenter:CGPointMake(background.frame.size.width - (hasCouponImageView.frame.size.width * 2.4), background.frame.size.height * 0.45)];
            [infoWindow addSubview:hasCouponImageView];
        }

        locationName.text = parkingLot.locationName;
    }

    return infoWindow;
}

- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapInfoWindowOfMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker
{
    ParkingLot *parkingLot = [marker userData];

    [self.delegate pushToParkingLot:parkingLot];
}

- (BOOL)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker
{

    if ([self.mapView isEqual:self.informationWindowsMarker.map])
    {
        if(marker.position.latitude != self.informationWindowsMarker.position.latitude  &&
           marker.position.longitude != self.informationWindowsMarker.position.longitude)
        {
            [self.informationWindowsMarker setOpacity:1];
            TRACE(@"%@", [self.informationWindowsMarker debugDescription]);
        }
    }

    self.informationWindowsMarker = nil;

    self.informationWindowsMarker = marker;

    [marker setOpacity:0];

    return NO;
}

- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
{
    if ([self.mapView isEqual:self.informationWindowsMarker.map])
    {
        ParkingLot *parkingLot = (ParkingLot *)self.informationWindowsMarker.userData;

        if (![self.informationWindowsMarker.icon isEqual:[parkingLot logoMarkerImage]])
        {
            self.informationWindowsMarker.icon = [parkingLot logoMarkerImage];
        }

        [self.informationWindowsMarker setOpacity:1];
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23130322/exc-bad-access-sigsegv-on-osx-10-9-2-with-qt-application?answertab=votes#tab-top. Maybe this answer could help.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue. Please, anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Removing

```
infoWindow.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
infoWindow.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
infoWindow.layer.borderColor = (__bridge CGColorRef)([UIColor blackColor]);
infoWindow.layer.borderWidth = 5;
```

**solved the crash**

I'm not quite sure why, but modifying layer's properties uses CoreAnimation, and that might use his own thread to change it afterwards generating an unstable state for Google's API